# B2C reset password

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have following in my startup:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AadInstance"];
    private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
    private static string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];

    // B2C policy identifiers
   // public static string SignUpPolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:SignUpPolicyId"];
    public static string SignInUpPolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:SignInUpPolicyId"];
    public static string DefaultPolicy = SignInUpPolicyId;
    public static string ResetPasswordPolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ResetPasswordPolicyId"];
    public static string ProfilePolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:UserProfilePolicyId"];



    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        // Configure OpenID Connect middleware for each policy
       app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignInUpPolicyId));
       //app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(ResetPasswordPolicyId));
       // app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignInPolicyId));
    }



    private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        notification.HandleResponse();

        // Handle the error code that Azure AD B2C throws when trying to reset a password from the login page
        // because password reset is not supported by a "sign-up or sign-in policy"
        if (notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription != null && notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
        {
            // If the user clicked the reset password link, redirect to the reset password route
            notification.Response.Redirect("/Account/ResetPassword");
        }
        else if (notification.Exception.Message == "access_denied")
        {
            notification.Response.Redirect("/");
        }
        else
        {
            notification.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + notification.Exception.Message);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        var policy = notification.OwinContext.Get<string>("Policy");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy) && !policy.Equals(DefaultPolicy))
        {
            //notification.ProtocolMessage.Scope = OpenIdConnectScopes.OpenId;
            //notification.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseTypes.IdToken;
            notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.Replace(DefaultPolicy, policy);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromPolicy(string policy)
    {
        return new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // For each policy, give OWIN the policy-specific metadata address, and
            // set the authentication type to the id of the policy
            MetadataAddress = String.Format(aadInstance, tenant, policy),
            AuthenticationType = policy,

            // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
            ClientId = clientId,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
            },
            Scope = "openid",
            ResponseType = "id_token",

            // This piece is optional - it is used for displaying the user's name in the navigation bar.
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
                SaveSigninToken = true //important to save the token in boostrapcontext
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In my Controller I have following:

```
public void ResetPassword()
{
    // Let the middleware know you are trying to use the reset password 
    policy (see OnRedirectToIdentityProvider in Startup.Auth.cs)
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Set("Policy", Startup.ResetPasswordPolicyId);

        // Set the page to redirect to after changing passwords
        var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" };
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(authenticationProperties);
}
```

Right now the reset password just redirect to "/". I am not sure how this works, and havent been able to find any samples. I tried following this sample but it uses some cores libraries and havent succeeded using the documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi

After following Chris suggestion it worked. See image below when clicking reset password.
[image]

Comment: Hi Thomas. You are mixing a few approaches in the above code. I suggest you follow [this Startup file](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs) as closely as possible to get yourself started.

Comment: Thanks seems like it did the work. Can you post an answer. Do you know if you can prevent users from chaning email during the reset password process (see image in original post)? We use the email as identifier for the user, so its not an option they change email.

Comment: Hi @Thomas. "Change e-mail" enables the end user to change the email address to which the verification code is sent. It doesn't enable them to change the email address that is registered for their local account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow [this `Startup.Auth.cs` file](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs) as closely as possible to get yourself started.

The `ConfigureAuth` method of the `Startup` class registers the OWIN OpenID Connect middleware that enables an ASP.NET MVC controller to set the Azure AD B2C policy, to be redirected to, using the OWIN context.

Example:

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Set("Policy", Startup.ResetPasswordPolicyId);
```